# Saxon transformer version 11.3 - memory leak

Tags: saxon

I upgraded from saxon transformer version 9 to 11.3. My application is facing memory leak issue.

- Java spring boot application
- Application is multi threaded
- The application has 10 different transformer and process different xsl
- The memory occupied grows over time and takes up all available memory
- Tried to reuse transformer and to use new transformer every time we transform.(No luck)

Comment: It might be better to raise an issue (with more details about which Saxon 9 version exactly and some more information about the type and details of the XML input, XSLT code, output and the memory problems) on https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/issues

Comment: Thanks, this issue is solved in 11.4. https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5607

Answer (score 0):

As Martin says, this kind of question is more suited to the Saxonica support forums than here. The reason is that it probably involves an iterative process of investigation, which doesn't fit well with the StackOverflow question/answer format (where, if I don't immediately have the answer, someone is likely to flag my response as "not an answer").

The term "memory leak" is rather inaccurate when applied to Java. A memory leak is when objects that are no longer referenced are not releasing their memory, but the problem here is (almost certainly) that objects are still referenced when you don't want them to be.

To investigate the problem you need to get a heap dump and find out where the problem lies. It may be obvious that there are millions of objects of a particular class that shouldn't be there. A heap dump analyser will enable you to find out where these objects are referenced from, which will explain why they are not being garbage-collected.

You could proceed either by getting a heap dump and sending it to Saxonica (if you can't analyse it yourself), or by creating a repro of the failing application and sending that. My guess, given that it's a fairly complex application, is that first approach is going to be easier for you.

We try to draw some lines around the level of support we're prepared to provide. One of those boundaries is that we won't attempt to run a repro that has complex dependencies, e.g. that requires third-party products to be installed. That would include Spring.

Note: different people adopt different strategies for problem solving, but personally, when I see something like this that worked in release X and doesn't work in release Y, I will usually investigate under release Y from first principles, rather than exploring what has changed. But there are exceptions, for example we know that Saxon 11 uses a completely new approach to catalog-bsed URI resolution and that will sometimes give clues as to where it's worth looking. So: it probably doesn't matter what release X was, but you should be aware that "Saxon 9" describes a series of ten major releases from 9.0 in 2008 to 9.9 in 2020, and it therefore isn't a very useful definition of your baseline.

Comment: Thanks, got my answer here (https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5607)